# MySQL : Getting DB row with exact same data from a vector

Tags: mysql

I have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `x_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `x_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 90),
    (1, 91),
    (1, 92),
    (2, 90),
    (2, 91),
    (2, 92),
    (2, 93)
;
```

and I have a vector [ 90,91,92]. My query is this simple :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM Table1 WHERE x_id IN ( 90,91,92);
```

which correctly returns both of them. How can I get only the id where the x_ids value match exactly my vector?

Comment: What do you mean by  *x_ids value match exactly my vector* ?

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way (assuming each combination of id and x_id is unique):

```
SELECT id 
  FROM table1 
 GROUP 
    BY id 
HAVING SUM(x_id IN (90,91,92)) = COUNT(x_id)  
   AND COUNT(*) = 3;
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than the initially accepted answer.  I went with the same approach, but with an extra JOIN to only run the aggregate functions for rows that contained at least one of the target values -- which is a helpful optimization on a huge table. Yours is likely good enough for most cases, and much simpler to follow.

Answer (score 3):

I like to assume that there are millions of rows in the dataset, since that heavily influences query design.

With that in mind, you could do something like:

```
SELECT id, 
SUM(x_id IN (90,91,92)) AS score,
SUM(1) AS count
FROM Table1
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE x_id IN (90,91,92)
)
GROUP BY id
HAVING score = count AND count = 3;
```

That will only consider rows that have an `x_id` matching 90, 91, or 92. It calculates a `score` for how many `x_id` values match for each `id`. It also calculates the `count` of distinct `x_id` values per `id`. That helps us exclude IDs that have values for 90, 91, and 92, but also have additional values.

An exact vector match would have a `score` equal to the `count`.

This approach should be more efficient on a table with millions of rows, since only a subset of those rows will reference at least one of the target values.

It makes the assumption that each `(id, x_id)` tuple is unique.

**Edit:**

Fixed the `HAVING count = 3` issue in the example, as reported by [@Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833873/mysql-getting-db-row-with-exact-same-data-from-a-vector/46835267?noredirect=1#comment80643066_46835267) in the comments.

When using subqueries like this, make sure you're using a recent version of MySQL. MySQL 5.5 and earlier has poor subquery performance due to the query planner ignoring keys and doing expensive scans.

To demonstrate the performance improvement of the extra subquery, we can generate a bunch of sample data to insert into `Table1`.  Here's a simple PHP script that generates 100,000 rows with random vectors of length 2-5 with values between 1-100:

```
<?php
$possible_values = range(1,100);

foreach(range(1,100000) as $id) {
    $vector = array_rand($possible_values, mt_rand(2,5));

    $values = array_map(function($x_id) use ($id) {
        return sprintf("(%d, %d)", $id, $x_id);
    }, $vector);

    echo sprintf("INSERT INTO Table1 (id, x_id) VALUES %s;\n",
        implode(',', $values)
    );
}
```

We'll assume the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table1` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `x_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`, `x_id`)
  KEY `x_id` (`x_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Let's compare the benefit of the subquery optimization to find a short vector:

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, 
    -> SUM(x_id IN (6,25)) AS score,
    -> SUM(1) AS count
    -> FROM Table1
    -> WHERE id IN (
    -> SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE x_id IN (6,25)
    -> )
    -> GROUP BY id
    -> HAVING score = count AND count = 2;
+-------+-------+-------+
| id    | score | count |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 15265 |     2 |     2 |
| 40816 |     2 |     2 |
| 75000 |     2 |     2 |
| 75239 |     2 |     2 |
| 83498 |     2 |     2 |
+-------+-------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id 
    -> FROM table1 
    -> GROUP BY id 
    -> HAVING SUM(x_id IN (6,25)) = COUNT(x_id) 
    -> AND COUNT(*) = 2;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 15265 |
| 40816 |
| 75000 |
| 75239 |
| 83498 |
+-------+
5 rows in set (0.14 sec)
```

The optimization is **100ms** faster (it takes 29% of the time as the unoptimized query).

You can see why with `EXPLAIN`.

Unoptimized we're scanning almost the entire table:

```
mysql> explain SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id  FROM table1  GROUP BY id  HAVING SUM(x_id IN (6,25)) = COUNT(x_id)  AND COUNT(*) = 2 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: table1
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: id
          key: id
      key_len: 10
          ref: NULL
         rows: 338846
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Optimized:

```
mysql> explain SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id,  SUM(x_id IN (6,25)) AS score, SUM(1) AS count FROM Table1 WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE x_id IN (6,25) ) GROUP BY id HAVING score = count AND count = 2 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: <subquery2>
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: NULL
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Table1
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: id
          key: id
      key_len: 5
          ref: <subquery2>.id
         rows: 3
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: MATERIALIZED
        table: Table1
   partitions: NULL
         type: range
possible_keys: x_id,id
          key: x_id
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 6874
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

In the optimization, we're able to limit the subset of rows we're aggregating from ~338,846 to only ~6,874.  That's a **lot** less work for MySQL to do.

For a longer vector, like `19,61,62,96`, the optimized query runs in **80ms** vs **150ms** with a table scan (almost twice as fast).

The extra complexity may not be worth saving **100ms**, but if `Table1` had millions of rows, the performance of the optimized query would become very apparent compared to the unoptimized approach of aggregating the entire table.

Comment: Thanks! Good catch on the `HAVING count = 3`. I must have mistakingly optimized that out along the way. I fixed that in my example. But you're right that a subset of the search vector would have still matched at a smaller length. Regarding performance, I'll give it a test. Those numbers sound very unusual. Any chance you're still on MySQL 5.5? It has pretty terrible subquery performance.

Comment: The version I tested on is even older than that, actually, so I'd be interested to see how it does on your machine (relative to my query, of course).

Comment: I just ran a test against a table with 25,000 `id` entries with randomized `x_id` vectors of length 2-5 with values between 1-100.  I added a compound index for `(id,x_id)`. Both of our queries returned in ~60-70ms on MySQL 5.7.18.

Comment: I also wouldn't expect to see an improvement on my extra `WHERE` subquery step until there was *much* more data. I routinely deal with tables that have millions of rows, so I'm always having to do extra optimizations like the above to avoid full table scans. I believe this consideration is worthwhile to note as an addendum, but your answer deserves to be the accepted one. Your query is cleaner and simpler, and could be used until query performance relative to row count becomes an issue.

Comment: I added some comparisons to the answer.